# Bordism between singular spheres and singular tori

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose I have a singular manifold $f: S^n \times S^n \times \dots \times S^n \rightarrow X$ such that the restriction of $f$ to the wedge sum $S^n \vee S^n \vee \dots \vee S^n$ is constant. This implies $f$ factors through $f':S^n \wedge S^n \dots \wedge S^n =S^{kn} \rightarrow X$. Of course since both $S^n \times S^n \times \dots \times S^n$ and $S^{kn}$ are null bordant, there are many bordisms between the two.

Is it the case that $f$ and $f'$ are bordant as singular manifolds? I ask because in Watanabe's paper "On Kontsevich's Characteristic Classes for Higher Dimensional Sphere Bundles II" in the proof of the main theorem (6.1), Watanabe uses this to conclude something about the image of the Hurewicz map for oriented bordism.

Comment: Careful. The iterated smash $S^n\wedge\dots\wedge S^n$ is the quotient of $S^n\times\dots\times S^n$ by the *fat* wedge $\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mid x_i=\ast\;\text{some}\;i\}$, rather than the wedge $S^n\vee\dots\vee S^n$ (where $n-1$ points are the basepoint). The point is that $f$ need not factor through $S^n\wedge\dots\wedge S^n$ if it is only null-homotopic on the wedge. Think about $f$ being the projection onto two factors followed by the quotient to the smash.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks for pointing that out. I’ll have to check again to see exactly what he claims, though I think with your correction the question is still reasonable (but I feel like such a thing should not be true).

Comment: @Tyrone I think, unfortunately, Watanabe makes the same mistake I did. From his paper: "$S^{2n(k−1) }=(S^{k−1})^{\times 2n}/S^{k−1} \vee \dots \vee S^{k−1}$".

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand too much of Watanabe's paper, so I don't know what he's doing, but I found that part and its weird. The example I gave above $S^n\times S^n\times S^n\xrightarrow{\pi_{2,3}}S^n\times S^n\xrightarrow{\wedge}S^{2n}$ is a map which is trivial on the wedge but does not factor through $S^{3n}$ (check cohomology).

Comment: @Tyrone Yeah, I believe it. You can also very easily check it for the $S^0$ case by arithmetic. I think it is just a mistake in the paper.